# Laravel - Storage Crop Image Intervention

Tags: laravel, imagen, archivo

Tengo un problema con el almacenamiento en Storage Utilizando Image Intervention. Actualmente tengo mi codigo funcional, el problema es que necesitor hacer crop a la image para redimencionarla.

```
$file   = $request->file('avatar');
$path = Auth::user()->id . '/' . $type__acount . '/';
File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
$avatar  = Storage::disk('public')->put($path , $file);
```

Implementando `Image Invention`

```
$file   = $request->file('avatar');
$path = Auth::user()->id . '/' . $type__acount . '/';
$crop = Image::make($file);
$crop->resize(100, 100, function($constraint){
   $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->encode('jpg');

File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
$avatar  = Storage::disk('public')->put($path , $crop);
```

Pero me arroja un `"message": "file_put_contents(/home/kllaar/public_html/api_service/public/storage/866851/trainer): failed to open stream: Is a directory",`

¿Alguien sabe que esta sucediendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así es, te falta añadir en tu `$path` el nombre de archivo de como quedará la imagen, tu ruta completa sería por ejemplo: `home/kllaar/public_html/api_service/public/storage/866851/trainer/tu-imagen.jpg`

Entonces quedaría:

```
    $file   = $request->file('avatar');
    $fileName = uniqid() . time() . '.jpeg';
    $path = Auth::user()->id . '/' . $type__acount . '/';

    $img = Image::make($file)->fit(100)->encode('jpeg');

    File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path.$fileName, 0777, true, true);

    $avatar  = Storage::disk('public')->put($path.$fileName, $img);
```

Comment: ¿Ese nombre hace referencia a como se va a llamar mi archivo?

Comment: @DoubleM Exacto, yo solo puse un ejemplo pero tu puedes llamarla como te plazca.

Answer (score 0):

```html
        public function subir_foto(Request $request){

            //Se declara el tipo de guardado
            Storage::disk('local');

            //capturar el nombre del archivo
            $nombre = time().$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

            //guardar la imagen en Storage
            $path = Storage::putFileAs(
                'img/', $request->file('file'), time().$nombre
            );
            
            //Ubicación de la imagen
            $real_path = public_path('/storage'.'/'.$path);

            //Cambiar de tamaño segun el aspecto
            Image::make($real_path)
                ->resize(900, null, function ($constraint){
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })
                ->save($real_path,72);

            //Retornar URL
            return $real_path;
        }
```

`introducir el código aquí`Revisa toda la info aquí https://codigosdeabner.blogspot.com/2021/09/cambiar-tamano-redimensionar-imagen.html

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Escribe un breve resumen del enlace que proporcionas: recuerda que su contenido puede que ya no esté disponible más adelante, volviendo obsoleta a la respuesta. Además, ¿cómo resuelve el código el inconveniente del OP (autor de la pregunta)? Lee [answer].